# writeUTF(String s) vs writeObject(String s)

Tags: java, networking, serialization, dataoutputstream

In this Java project I'm working on for university, I have a situation where I am currently sending strings through the network successfully using

```
streamOut = ObjectOutputStream
streamIn = ObjectInputStream

streamOut.writeUTF(msgs.peek());
```

where msgs is a linked blocking queue, receiving it with

```
String in = streamIn.readUTF();
```

however, I would like to use an ObjectInputStream and an ObjectOutputStream. I have initialized them both in the constructor and I flush the ObjectOutputStream after constructing it, I read somewhere you have to do this.

I want to send both Strings and another Object type, call it gameWorld over the network (don't care about efficiency at this point).. however when I do

```
streamOut.writeObject("mad cuz i'm bad");

Object in = streamIn.readObject(); 
if(in instanceof String) String inS = (String) in;
```

it doesn't pick anything up when I send strings over... my friend is working on the same project and he passes around only 1 type of object, one of the subclasses of this object is essentially a string and his version works fine, but he makes a new stream in every iteration of his thread's run loop.

Do I need to do something with the stream to receive different objects which don't have a common ancestor other than Object, do I need to make a new stream every iteration of the run loop or is there just something else completely that I'm missing and the information I've provided isn't sufficient to tell whats wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that `Object in = streamIn.readObject(); ` after this line in is null ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a significant difference between writing a String into the stream as primitive data or as an Object. A String instance written by writeObject is written into the stream as a String initially. Future writeObject() calls write references to the string into the stream.

For Example

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos1=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    oos1=new ObjectOutputStream(baos1);
    baos2=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos2=new ObjectOutputStream(baos2);
    String testString="First";
    oos1.writeObject(testString);
    oos2.writeUTF(testString);
    testString="Second";
    oos1.writeObject(testString);
    oos2.writeUTF(testString);
    testString="Third";
    oos1.writeObject(testString);
    oos2.writeUTF(testString);
    oos1.flush();
    oos2.flush();
    byte[] byteArray1=baos1.toByteArray();
    byte[] byteArray2=baos2.toByteArray();
```

Dump last two arrays you will get result like:
**writeObject** i.e. byteArray1 
Binary: -84 -19 0 5 116 0 5 70 105 114 115 116 116 0 6 83 101 99 111 110 100 116 0 5 84 104 105 114 100 
ASCII: -T -   **t**   F i r s t **t**   S e c o n d **t**   T h i r d

**writeUTF** i.e. byteArray2 
Binary: -84 -19 0 5 119 22 0 5 70 105 114 115 116 0 6 83 101 99 111 110 100 0 5 84 104 105 114 100 
ASCII: -T -   **w**    F i r s t   S e c o n d   T h i r d

**Conclusion:** In case of writeObject an extra data (here **t**)to be streamed whereas in case of writeUTF only the string data to be streamed.

For more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)

Comment: Boom, nailed it. Thank you, I didn't know about the reference thing, that was what got me and why my friends version worked by making a new stream every time.

Comment: There is no difference between those two hex dumps. You've posted the same one twice. The first one doesn't agree with the ASCII rendering given.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the string with readObject() you have to write it with writeObject().

Answer (score 0):

The most important difference is that if you write the String with `writeUTF()`, then the whole String will always be written into the stream as UTF encoded characters. But if you use `writeObject()`, then the Object instance of the String is written to the stream. So if you write multiple Strings of the same instance with `writeObject()`, then the corresponding Strings returned by `readObject()` will also be guaranteed to be the same Object instance, whereas when you read them with `readUTF()`, they will *not* be the same Object instance:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out1 = new ObjectOutputStream(bytes1);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out2 = new ObjectOutputStream(bytes2);

String writeString = "test";
out1.writeObject(writeString);
out1.writeObject(writeString);

out2.writeUTF(writeString);
out2.writeUTF(writeString);

out1.flush();
out2.flush();

ObjectInputStream in1 = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes1.toByteArray()));
ObjectInputStream in2 = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes2.toByteArray()));

String readString1 = (String) in1.readObject();
String readString2 = (String) in1.readObject();

System.out.println(readString1 == readString2);

readString1 = (String) in2.readUTF();
readString2 = (String) in2.readUTF();

System.out.println(readString1 == readString2);
```

Prints:

```
true
false
```

This also results in very different streams: With `writeUTF()` we get a byte[] of length 18 that includes the UTF characters "test" two times. With `writeObject()` we get a byte[] of length 16 that includes the UTF characters "test" only once, followed by an integer representing the reference id of the String. So `writeObject()` will usually result in a smaller file size. This can make a huge difference if a large number of Strings of the same instance are written to the stream (e.g. by calling `String.intern()`).